# Algorithms for maximizing the sum of power functions with linear constraints?

Tags: nonlinear-programming, convex-optimization

I’m working on an optimization problem that arises from maximizing the return obtained from investing in different marketing levers. The return from each lever exhibits diminishing returns, and is modeled using a power function to represent the saturation of investment. The problem can be mathematically described as:

\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    \max_{x}
    \quad & \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^p \\
    \textrm{s.t.} \quad & Ax = b
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Where:

- $x$ is a vector with dimension $n$
- $p$ is a constant between 0 and 1, representing the power to which each lever's investment is raised.
- $Ax = b$ are the linear constraints associated with the problem.

Is there a class of algorithms that aim to efficiently solve this kind of problem?

Comment: I presume you want to constraint $x \ge 0$. Trivial to input in DCP convex optimization modeling tool, which under the hood might use power cones or geometric mean to handle. Produces a nice convex optimization problem. Can enter directly  using special provided functions such as pow_pos.

Comment: Are there any bounds on $x$?

Comment: Given x has to be nonnegative you can formulate it as a conic optimization problem. See https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/powo.html

Answer (score 1):

Sequential least-squares from Scipy is able to [express this directly](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize):

> Method SLSQP uses Sequential Least SQuares Programming to minimize a function of several variables with any combination of bounds, equality and inequality constraints. The method wraps the SLSQP Optimization subroutine originally implemented by [Dieter Kraft](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#rdd2e1855725e-12)

It will behave the best if you give it the Jacobian analytically, and give it good bounds (unspecified on your question) and a good starting vector. You haven't offered dimensions for $A$ or $b$ so it's unclear whether this is under-, over- or exactly-determined, but in every case a least-squares pre-solve will do its best to find an initial solution:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import Bounds, LinearConstraint, minimize, check_grad


def cost(x: np.ndarray, p: np.ndarray) -> float:
    return -(x**p).sum()


def jacobian(x: np.ndarray, p: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return -p*x**(p - 1)


m = 3
n = 7
rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
p = rand.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=n)
A = rand.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(m, n))
b = rand.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=m)

# Set x0 such that it initially satisfies the constraint
x0, *_ = np.linalg.lstsq(a=A, b=b, rcond=None)

error = check_grad(cost, jacobian, x0, p)
assert error < 1e-5

result = minimize(
    fun=cost, jac=jacobian, args=(p,),
    x0=x0, method='slsqp',
    bounds=Bounds(lb=0),
    constraints=LinearConstraint(A=A, lb=b, ub=b),
)
assert result.success, result.message
print(result.x)
```